# what is causing this error : invalid literal for int() with base 10

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-views

Hello I'm developing a simple posts app using Django

I have to models user and post model
i'm to get all posts sent to a specific user I got this error message while trying to get the posts

```py
invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'user1'
```

these are the models 
 
**user model**

```py
class MyUser(AbstractBaseUser):
    email = models.EmailField(verbose_name="email", max_length=60, unique=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='date joined', auto_now_add=True)
    last_login = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='last login', auto_now=True)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)</pre>
```

**post model**

```py
class Post(models.Model):
    # post structure
    user = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, default="Anonymous")  # sender
    content = models.TextField(blank=False)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    toUser = models.ForeignKey(MyUser, null=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    post_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)</pre>
```

I'm getting the username variable sent in the URL in this view
and trying to get all posts sent to this username

```py
def user_posts(request, username):

    posts = Post.objects.get(toUser=username)

    return render(request=request,
                  template_name='post/user.html',
                  context={'posts', posts})
```

this is urls.py file 
**urls.py**

```py
from django.urls import path
from. import views

app_name = "post"
urlpatterns = [

    path("", views.home, name="homepage"),
    path("register/", views.register, name="register"),
    path("logout/", views.logut_request, name="logout"),
    path("login/", views.login_request, name="login"),
    path("home/<username>", views.user_posts, name="get_Posts"),



]
```

**user.html** file

```html
{% for p in posts %}
<div class="col s12 m6 l8">
    <div class="card blue darken-4">
           <div class="card-content white-text">
           <span class="card-title">from:{{ p.toUser }}</span>
               <p>{{ p.content }}</p>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>




{% endfor %}
```

Comment: add full traceback please

Comment: Somewhere in your model you are trying to convert `user1` into an integer

Comment: question updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is here:

```
posts = Post.objects.get(toUser=username)
```

`toUser` is a `ForeignKey` to the `MyUser` model, and as such you can reference the value by passing in either an entire object of that model, or its id. Here you a passing a string in `username`, which doesn't work - it appears Django is trying to convert that into an `int` id, and throwing an error when it can't.

You clearly want to look up a user by username, since this is a unique field. To do that, you could first look up the user by username, and then pass that in to the posts query:

```
user = MyUser.objects.get(username=username)
posts = Post.objects.filter(toUser=user)
```

or, more concisely, use a lookup that spans the relationships:

```
posts = Post.objects.filter(toUser__username=username)
```

Note that I've changed your use of `get` to `filter`, because `get` is only for queries which are expected to return *exactly one* result, and there is nothing in your models which suggests that user will only have one post each.

Full Django query API is [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/queries/) - I recommend you give it a good read.

Answer (score 0):

You need to follow the foreign key relationship in your filter.

```
posts = Post.objects.get(toUser=username)
```

tries to compare the key itself to the username string, which is an integer id . You need to do this.

```
posts = Post.objects.get(toUser__username=username)
```